# Is JSP necessary for Angular2 security for different roles

Tags: performance, angular, jsp, security

I am build an application using Angular2 as front end framework and spring boot as backend framework.

One of the seniors in my team insisted on using JSP as templates for my components in order to avoid rendering any unauthorized views.

Is that really nessecary? I saw many applications which are implemented using angular or other front end frameworks but it did not render the templates in backend, is it a good practice? isn't authenticating the requests is enough?

Also would not that be a problem for performance?

From my point of view I think JSP will prevent us from using the potentials of Angular, any help or documentation on that subject would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to use JSP in Angular 2.

It's correct that JSP allows you to protect the template itself from unauthorized access, but in our case it's not really a bad thing to happen from the security point of view, as access to the template without the data itself is not something dangerous; The data of course must be protected w/ your own security/authentication to prevent unwanted access to it.

Answer (score 2):

**Short:** No, JSP is not necessary.

**Long:** One has to realize where which part runs. JSP on the server, Angular in the browser. I assume your senior colleague is concerned about displaying unauthorized data - but that is not the concern of Angular. Angular is basically just the View, and, perhaps, Controller. But it has to get the data from the server - which is usually done over some REST service. And it is the duty of that service to serve only data the user is allowed to view. So you can implement your View/Controller part in Angular, putting all the views (event the restricted ones) in, and then implement proper security into your server-side data service.